# How to create an inner popup in JavaFX styled with FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have an FXML file that I'm using to allow user input when requested. Right now I just put it in a new stage and do `Stage.show()`. I would like to not have it appear in a new window and behave more like a `ContextMenu`.

Looking at `ContextMenu` class it doesn't appear that I can set the content based off an FXML file. Is there a way to do this either with `ContextMenu` or `Popup` or some other class I am unaware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although that library is quite nice, I wanted something simple that didn't require 3rd party downloads. I came up with this:

```
Popup popup = new Popup();
CustomController controller = new CustomController();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlfile));
loader.setController(controller);
popup.getContent().add((Parent)loader.load());
```

The problem was I didn't realize that a `Parent` could be considered a `Node` for the method `Popup#getContent#add`

Answer (score 0):

[ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) has a PopOver control you might like. That PopOver can use any Node for its content, so you can simply create a popover, load a node from FXML and set the content of the popover to that node.