# popUp showed up using netbeans run , but not with the jar file ,JAVAFX

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, popup

i have a problem , i'm trying to open a popUp window with javaFX , 
in netbeans , work fine , but after trying the jar files it doesn't show , 
after running with cmd , i get this error ,

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException:


Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at frame.login.LoginController.showPopupWindow(LoginController.java:144)


at frame.login.LoginController.lambda$initialize$0(LoginController.java:
114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.h
andleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEve
nt$354(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

showPopupWindow() to show the popup :

```
  @FXML
 private void showPopupWindow() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Popup.fxml"));

        // initializing the controller
        PopUpController popupController = new PopUpController();
        loader.setController(popupController);
        Parent layout;
        try {
            layout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

            // this is the popup stage
            Stage popupStage = new Stage();
            // now
            popupController.setStage(popupStage);
            if(this.main!=null) {
                popupStage.initOwner(main.getPrimaryStage());
            }
            popupStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            popupStage.setScene(scene);
            popupStage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "There was an error trying to load the popup fxml file.").show();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Which lines are line 114 and 144 in LoginController?

Comment: layout = loader.load(); //144

Comment: showPopupWindow(); //114

Comment: 144 is your problem

Answer (score 0):

> Stackoverflow likes this answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448611/how-to-create-an-inner-popup-in-javafx-styled-with-fxml):

```
Popup popup = new Popup();
CustomController controller = new CustomController();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlfile));
loader.setController(controller);
popup.getContent().add((Parent)loader.load());
```